# wpf create a textbox with a button for openfiledialog

Tags: wpf, user-controls, datatemplate

I'm using a **DataTemplate** for a type that has a property which is the file address.  I need to create a `TextBox` with a `Button` which will open an `OpenFileDialog` and then insert the selected file address into the `TextBox`.

I wanna know what's the best way for creating the `TextBox` and the `Button` next to it which will show the `OpenFileDialog`. And don't forget that this is a `DataTemplate` so as I know I don't have any codebehind for the `DataTemplate`.

I was thinking about a `UserControl` but I don't if that's the best way or not?

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UserControl is a perfectly acceptable solution, but I would be more likely to use either 1) a custom control, or 2) a RoutedUICommand.

**Building a Custom Control**

Create a simple control derived from TextBox:

```
public class TextBoxWithFileDialog : TextBox
{
  static TextBoxWithFileDialog()
  {
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextBoxWithFileDialog), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TextBoxWithFileDialog)));
    CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(TextBoxWithFileDialog), new CommandBinding(
      ApplicationCommands.Open,
      (obj, e) => { e.Handled = true; ((TextBoxWithFileDialog)obj).ShowFileOpenDialog(); },
      (obj, e) => { e.CanExecute = true; }));
  }
  void ShowFileOpenDialog()
  {
    var dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog
    {
      DefaultExt = ".txt"
    };
    if(dialog.ShowDialog()==true)
      Text = dialog.FileName;
  }
}
```

then in themes/Generic.xaml or a resource dictionary included from it add a style containing an appropriate ControlTemplate:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxWithFileDialog}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxWithFileDialog}">

        <DockPanel>
          <Button Content="..." Command="Open" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
          <!-- copy original TextBox control template contents here -->
        </DockPanel>

    ... close rest of tags ...
```

You can copy TextBox's existing ControlTemplate using Expression Blend or Reflector/BamlViewer).

For my own projects I would prefer to add a solution like this to my control library so I can use it anywhere I want.  However this may be overkill if you're only going to use it once.  In that case I would just:

**Using a RoutedUICommand**

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window
{
  public Window()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    ...
    CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(TextBoxWithFileDialog), new CommandBinding(
      ApplicationCommands.Open,
      (obj, e) =>
      {
        e.Handled = true;
        ((MyWindow)obj).ShowFileOpenDialog((TextBox)e.Parameter);
      },
      (obj, e) => { e.CanExecute = true; }));
  }
  void ShowFileOpenDialog(TextBox textBox)
  {
    var dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog
    {
      DefaultExt = ".txt"
    };
    if(dialog.ShowDialog()==true)
      textBox.Text = dialog.FileName;
  }
}
```

This does not require a style or an additional class.  Just name your textbox, and have the button refer to the textbox as its command parameter:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Whatever" ... />
<Button Content="..." Command="Open" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Whatever}" />
```

That's all there is to it.  Unfortunately it only works in one window, and putting it somewhere else would require cut-and-paste.  That's why I prefer a custom control.

**Note**

If you're already using ApplicationCommands.Open elsewhere in your application, you might select a different command, or create your own:

```
public static readonly RoutedUICommand MyCommand = new RoutedUICommand(...)
```